# Getting mkdir error while using uploading image using multer

Tags: node.js, mongoose, image-uploading, mongoose-schema, multer

while uploading file and creating a path , I am getting creating a folder error :-

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/bitnami/apps/NodeJS-Login/uploads'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at Function.sync (/opt/bitnami/apps/NodeJS-Login/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at new DiskStorage (/opt/bitnami/apps/NodeJS-Login/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:21:12)
    at module.exports (/opt/bitnami/apps/NodeJS-Login/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:65:10)
    at new Multer (/opt/bitnami/apps/NodeJS-Login/node_modules/multer/index.js:15:20)
```

I am using bitnami on AWS to host my MEAN app.

on my main **server.js** file I have added this:-

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
 rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
   return filename;
 },
}));
```

**on schema model** :-

```
companyLogo: {
                data: Buffer,
                type: String
                }
```

and in **controller** for route :-

```
admin.companyLogo = fs.readFileSync(req.files.comLogo.path)
admin.companyLogo.type = 'image/png';
```

*What should I do to make image upload ? Also do I have to pass other key values in form-data instead of raw ?*

Comment: You should probably fix the EACCES permission error.

Comment: @TGrif What is this error is about ? I am looking but all the ques is about local project. I am not getting why it is not creating folder on the hosted server

Answer (score 0):

/opt is write protected by default, so here are possible fixes

1) Change permissions for /opt and allow the user to write in this folder (**Not Recommended**)

OR

2) Run the server.js with the super user, this way you have complete right over the directory and it will allow you to do anything (**Not Recommended**)

OR

3) Just change the path to somewhere the user has access to write (**Recommended**)

Comment: This is already been hosted. So where do I suppose to give user to write access

Comment: use chmod -R 777 folderpath on bitnami console. But As I mentioned it is not recommended. It would be simple and better if you just go with option 3

Comment: If the project is hosted in bitnami then the folder to access uploading files should be there only I guess.

Comment: True for superuser, not for every user, other users can read only, no write hence no upload

Comment: But other user is secondary thing. The error is coming when I am trying to run the server only.  Who is superuser here exactly ?

Comment: superuser is commonly referred to as "root" or if you are  more comfortable with windows then it is the administrator; when you write sudo you mean to run the following command as superuser and not the logged in user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194770/discussion-between-mehul-mittal-and-noobcoder).